# Toilet flush stuck down

Tags: toilet

Our toilet flush button is stuck down, and the mechanism on the back doesn't appear to be attached properly.

It's a cable pull system.

Any ideas how it's supposed to be attached?

[image: flush button]

[image: mechanism]

[image: the other end]

Comment: Do you have the name or make and model of toilet/flush mechanism? What have you done, have you tried to take it apart to see how it may work?

Comment: What's the other end of the cable attached to? Have you looked to see if it's moving freely?

Comment: No makers mark. I don't want to pull it apart incase I can't put it back together. The other end connects to the central column, which is lifted up by a cable. I'll add that to the question.

Comment: It might be a "PRO550UK cable valve" system.

Comment: you probably should not be seeing all those threads in the middle picture

Comment: @jsotola the threads are on the plastic nut which holds the flush button in place. If I loosen the nut, the button can be repositioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it.

I pulled the blue plastic section away from the bottom of the threaded section. The 2 plastic parts of the flush button sprung back up, and I clipped the blue section back onto the base of the threaded section. I will add pictures later.

Comment: It is fun to take things apart, Especially when you can get them back together.

Comment: Give yourself a checkmark so others will know that this has a resolution!

Comment: I always forget about that. The whole come back in 2 days thing passes me by.